# How do I parse this nested JSON output in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a nested JSON output like this in Objective C:

```
{
-Status: {
code: 200
request: "geocode"
name: "1.304044,103.833867"
}
-Placemark: [
-{
-Point: {
-coordinates: [
103.834
1.30396
0
]
}
-AddressDetails: {
-Country: {
CountryName: "Singapore"
-Thoroughfare: {
ThoroughfareName: "Bus stop at Lucky Plaza (09048)"
}
CountryNameCode: "SG"
}
Accuracy: 9
}
id: "p1"
address: "Bus stop at Lucky Plaza (09048)"
}
-{
-Point: {
-coordinates: [
103.834
1.30444
0
]
}
-AddressDetails: {
-Country: {
CountryName: "Singapore"
AddressLine: "Lucky Plaza"
-Thoroughfare: {
-PostalCode: {
PostalCodeNumber: "238863"
}
ThoroughfareName: "304 Orchard Road"
}
CountryNameCode: "SG"
}
Accuracy: 9
}
id: "p2"
address: "Lucky Plaza, 304 Orchard Road, Singapore 238863"
}
-{
-Point: {
-coordinates: [
103.833
1.30376
0
]
}
-AddressDetails: {
-Country: {
CountryName: "Singapore"
AddressLine: "Wisma Atria"
-Thoroughfare: {
-PostalCode: {
PostalCodeNumber: "238877"
}
ThoroughfareName: "435 Orchard Road"
}
CountryNameCode: "SG"
}
Accuracy: 9
}
id: "p3"
address: "Wisma Atria, 435 Orchard Road, Singapore 238877"
}
-{
-Point: {
-coordinates: [
103.835
1.30389
0
]
}
-AddressDetails: {
-Country: {
CountryName: "Singapore"
-Thoroughfare: {
-PostalCode: {
PostalCodeNumber: "238860"
}
ThoroughfareName: "291 Orchard Road"
}
CountryNameCode: "SG"
}
Accuracy: 9
}
id: "p4"
address: "291 Orchard Road, Singapore 238860"
}
-{
-Point: {
-coordinates: [
103.834
1.30491
0
]
}
-AddressDetails: {
-Country: {
CountryName: "Singapore"
AddressLine: "Kimsia Park"
-Thoroughfare: {
-PostalCode: {
PostalCodeNumber: "228968"
}
ThoroughfareName: "1 Jalan Kayu Manis"
}
CountryNameCode: "SG"
}
Accuracy: 9
}
id: "p5"
address: "Kimsia Park, 1 Jalan Kayu Manis, Singapore 228968"
}
]
}
```

I have some code working, but I'm finding the nested nature of this to be pretty tough to figure out. What I'd like to get out is an array/dictionary which contains the following elements for each return record: coordinates, CountryName, ThoroughfareName, PostalCode and Accuracy.

Here is my test code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gothere.sg/maps/geo?output=json&ll=1.304044%2C103.833867&client=&sensor=false&callback="];

    NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

    self.jsonArray = [jsonData JSONValue]; 

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);

    [jsonURL release];
    [jsonData release];
}
```

My code just manages to get the raw JSON output, any thoughts/code to break it down as I've mentioned above.

Thanks!

As requested, some further information.

1. Using SBJson framework.
2. NSLog output from above:

   ```
   2011-08-30 16:44:32.605 Taxi[53070:207] {
   Placemark =     (
               {
           AddressDetails =             {
               Accuracy = 9;
               Country =                 {
                   CountryName = Singapore;
                   CountryNameCode = SG;
                   Thoroughfare =                     {
                       ThoroughfareName = "Bus stop at Lucky Plaza (09048)";
                   };
               };
           };
           Point =             {
               coordinates =                 (
                   "103.834",
                   "1.30396",
                   0
               );
           };
           address = "Bus stop at Lucky Plaza (09048)";
           id = p1;
       },
               {
           AddressDetails =             {
               Accuracy = 9;
               Country =                 {
                   AddressLine = "Lucky Plaza";
                   CountryName = Singapore;
                   CountryNameCode = SG;
                   Thoroughfare =                     {
                       PostalCode =                         {
                           PostalCodeNumber = 238863;
                       };
                       ThoroughfareName = "304 Orchard Road";
                   };
               };
           };
           Point =             {
               coordinates =                 (
                   "103.834",
                   "1.30444",
                   0
               );
           };
           address = "Lucky Plaza, 304 Orchard Road, Singapore 238863";
           id = p2;
       },
               {
           AddressDetails =             {
               Accuracy = 9;
               Country =                 {
                   AddressLine = "Wisma Atria";
                   CountryName = Singapore;
                   CountryNameCode = SG;
                   Thoroughfare =                     {
                       PostalCode =                         {
                           PostalCodeNumber = 238877;
                       };
                       ThoroughfareName = "435 Orchard Road";
                   };
               };
           };
           Point =             {
               coordinates =                 (
                   "103.833",
                   "1.30376",
                   0
               );
           };
           address = "Wisma Atria, 435 Orchard Road, Singapore 238877";
           id = p3;
       },
               {
           AddressDetails =             {
               Accuracy = 9;
               Country =                 {
                   CountryName = Singapore;
                   CountryNameCode = SG;
                   Thoroughfare =                     {
                       PostalCode =                         {
                           PostalCodeNumber = 238860;
                       };
                       ThoroughfareName = "291 Orchard Road";
                   };
               };
           };
           Point =             {
               coordinates =                 (
                   "103.83499999999999",
                   "1.30389",
                   0
               );
           };
           address = "291 Orchard Road, Singapore 238860";
           id = p4;
       },
               {
           AddressDetails =             {
               Accuracy = 9;
               Country =                 {
                   AddressLine = "Kimsia Park";
                   CountryName = Singapore;
                   CountryNameCode = SG;
                   Thoroughfare =                     {
                       PostalCode =                         {
                           PostalCodeNumber = 228968;
                       };
                       ThoroughfareName = "1 Jalan Kayu Manis";
                   };
               };
           };
           Point =             {
               coordinates =                 (
                   "103.834",
                   "1.30491",
                   0
               );
           };
           address = "Kimsia Park, 1 Jalan Kayu Manis, Singapore 228968";
           id = p5;
       }
   );
   Status =     {
       code = 200;
       name = "1.304044,103.833867";
       request = geocode;
   };
   ```

   }

Comment: post ur nslog json response output here

Comment: Also what framework are you using to parse your JSON? Have you tried JSONLint to see if the JSON validates?

Comment: you can get all the dictionaries from the JSON data in an array and then use valueForKey method to retrieve countryName,Thouroughfare name etc....

Comment: @booleanBoy -  I've come across what you've suggested, but am uncertain how to implement... any suggestions please?

Comment: First, have u obtained the data from JSON in a dictionary ?

Comment: Array. NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
  
 self.jsonArray = [jsonData JSONValue];

Comment: @makaron - I get a valid response if I pass the url http://gothere.sg/maps/geo?output=json&ll=1.304044%2C103.833867&client=&sensor=false&callback= to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
//NSMutableArray *addressDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *addressDetails = [[jsonArray valueForKey:@"Placemark"] valueForKey:@"AddressDetails"];

  //NSMutableArray *point = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *point = [[jsonArray valueForKey:@"Placemark"] valueForKey:@"Point"];

NSLog(@"%@", point);
NSLog(@"%@", [point objectAtIndex:0]);

NSLog(@"%@", addressDetails);
```

Like wise you can get array of "id" and "address" value also.

To get value of "coordinates" of point array, do this

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[point objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"coordinates"]);
```

For AddressDetails/Country/CountryName :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[addressDetails objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Country"] valueForKey:@"CountryName"]);
```

Comment: @spaleja: Where will be the arrays `addressDetails` and `point` be released? This code leaks memory.

Comment: you can release addressDetails and point array, once you will get invidual array from dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid, try to test it on http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ once it becames valid then only you can use it. You must have used the SBJSON framework to parse it.

Comment: Appears valid to me, see here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://gothere.sg/maps/geo?output=json&ll=1.304044%2C103.833867&client=&sensor=false&callback=